# Ignore Servlet loadOnStartup

Tags: java, tomcat, servlets

Well, I have this problem.

On Java Dynamic Web Project A, I have a servlet that is loaded on web startup, i.e.

```
@WebServlet(loadOnStartup = 1, urlPatterns = "/init")
public class InitializingServlet extends HttpServlet {
    @Override
    public void init() {
         // doing something
    }
}
```

And then, I bundle that Project A into a jar, and put it into Java Dynamic Web Project B's build path.
When I start project B in tomcat, the InitializingServlet in project A is run.
Well, I put project A into project B's build path only because I want to access the interface and object inside project A, but I don't want the InitializingServlet in project A is running on startup.

Is there a way of doing what I want?

Thank you very much

Comment: Move the code in project A into a third jar and reference the new jar from project A and project B.

Comment: You could put the loadOnStartup configuration to web.xml instead of using annotation in the class.

Comment: This is one of the reasons I hate annotation-processing.

Answer (score 0):

If you can survive without annotation-processing, set `metadata-complete="true"` in your `web.xml` for project B.